# Git: Reset, remove commit permanently

Tags: git

I have a file in .gitignore.

For a task, I need to

1. temporarily remove the entry in .gitignore for the file (or bypass it?)
2. add the file to the repo
3. perform some other tasks
4. undo my changes and ensure the commit is completely destroyed

I messed with git reset --HARD HEAD~1, but that blew away my un-tracked file.

git reset --soft will keep the commit around in the index.

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force add it to the repo use

```
git add -f fileName
git commit
```

Perform some other tasks

```
git reset HEAD^
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch to a new branch, do whatever with `.gitignore` and the relevant file, and then switch back to your old branch and delete the new one.